# C++ code library open error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, nunit

I am beginner developer in the VC++ environment. I used C++ code under the VS 2012 for NUnit Testing. 
I was trying a code in the test project but it keeps generating an error that a library file is not being opened. I checked in the project properties and there is a library named: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib

but it still generats an error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib'

Does anybody solved such problems before or you remmend me to do ?

Comment: The question is not whether the library is in the project properties. The question is whether there is a file called Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib on your hard disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I had this Problem too. I am working on VS express 2013, and I had created a new unit for an unmanaged dll and a test unit, which refers to.

To overcome,

- I found out, where the named `CppUniTestFramework.lib` is. It is not, where your VS Project files are.
  I found it under `C:\Program Files(86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\lib`
- I navigated to the file in Windows Explorer, copied the pathname out of properties and added this in Unit test Project properties under
  Linker - > Allgemein -> zusätzliche Bibliotheksverzeichnisse (Linker - > General - > Additional Library Directories).

I feel, this is not a nice solution, but it works now. I see now my first unit tests running.

Comment: Using `$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib` is what worked for me. I have a VS2012 project (v110) being compiled with VS2013 (v120). There is a difference between `VCInstallDir` and `VSInstallDir` defined at [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx).